# bitwise operations in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, simd

It doesn't seem like Eigen supports bitwise operations.

I would like bitwise SIMD functionality for "shift left" and "and".

Is there a quick and dirty way to implement this functionality? Can i call an intrinsic function and input it with something like Eigen vector.data()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Eigen don't support this because that there isn't a good way to do this for float, double and complex numbers.

You can always override those C++ bitwise operators by yourself, taking two MatrixBase as parameters.

For bitwise assignment operators, you need to add a function **inside** MatrixBase class.
Eigen made this possible, see [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html) how to.